# Generate two kinds of random variables for each step with same probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, probability, distribution

goal: Make two kinds of poisson random variables(λ=30, 60)

condition:

1. We have an array made with the following code(np.random.binomial(n=1, p=1/2, size=1000))
2. If the number in the array is 1, then we make a poisson random variables(λ=30)
   else we make a poisson random variables(λ=60)

So I wrote the code like this

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=1/2, size=1000)
b = np.where(a==1, np.random.poisson(lam=30), np.random.poisson(lam=60))
print(b)
```

But the result was like this

```
[62 62 28 ... 28 28 62]
```

Fixed random variables were continually being created.

So how can I get the result that random variables are not fixed?
(I don't wanna use loop(for or while))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BlackRaven's answer works fine, but the use of `np.vectorize` uses a Python loop "behind the scenes", so it is not as efficient as it could be.  An alternative is to use `a` to create a *vector* (i.e. 1-d NumPy array) of lambda values to pass to `poisson()`, like this (note that I've switched to the newer random interface of NumPy):

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
a = rng.binomial(n=1, p=1/2, size=1000)  # array containing 0 and 1
lam = 30 + (1-a)*30                      # array containing 30 and 60
b = rng.poisson(lam=lam)                 # mixture of Poisson samples
```

Of course, you don't have to create a named variable to hold the lambda values:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()
a = rng.binomial(n=1, p=1/2, size=1000)  # array containing 0 and 1
b = rng.poisson(lam=30 + (1-a)*30)       # mixture of Poisson samples
```

All the loops involved are now performed within NumPy functions that are implemented in C.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer! It really runs so fast.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the parameters in `np.where` are evaluated before it's called, so it's exactly the same as if you write

```py
value1 = np.random.poisson(lam=30)
value2 = np.random.poisson(lam=60)
b = np.where(a==1, value1, value2)
```

Use a for loop would be a good solution but if you don't want to do that, you can try something with np.vectorize

```py
def poisson(x):
    return np.random.poisson(lam=30) if x == 1 else np.random.poisson(lam=60)

b = np.vectorize(poisson)(a)
```

should works for example.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. I think using the map function also be the way to solve this problem. Then is there any possible solution without making any function like 'def poisson(x)'?

Comment: Vectorize is supposed to be more efficient when working with array, but it's really similar to map, yes.
You can't really do it without any function, buy if you don't want to define it, you can use a lambda function : `b = np.vectorize(lambda x: np.random.poisson(lam=30) if x == 1 else np.random.poisson(lam=60))(a)`